# Request Permission to Access gallery on button click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button in `Xamarin.Forms` that will allow a user to upload an image from their phone's gallery, however by default the permission is off for the app. I was wondering how to prompt the user to allow the permissions without having to go into the device's settings (possibly on button click).

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: Connor as Jason mentioned, you should look into using the Permissions Plugin, which greatly simplifies this. Here's an in depth article written by James Montemagno https://montemagno.com/simplified-ios-android-runtime-permissions-with/